# Add static cell in dynamic tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am trying to add a static cell as the first cell in my dynamic tableview. I have seen other questions on here but they do not seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. I actually get my cell, but it is replacing my first dynamic cell and when i scroll in my table view, my app crashes.

Here is what i have arrived at so far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
 CustomSideBarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

if (indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS) { 

cell.sidePic.image = _secondImage; 
cell.sideOption.text = @"Everything"; 

return cell; 

} 

else { 

cell.sidePic.image = _secondImage; 
_tempResults = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
_optionCategory = [[_tempResults objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"category_name"]; 
cell.sideOption.text = _optionCategory;
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: well like i mentioned, the first problem is that my static cell "overwrites" or replaces the first dynamic cell instead of being above it. Second problem is the app crashes when i try to scroll in the tableview.

Comment: this is the error that is thrown: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (14) beyond bounds (14)'

Comment: show us your crash log.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (14) beyond bounds (14)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2ed2df4b 0x3916e6af 0x2ed2de8d 0x2ec784b3 0x9562b 0x315d2a5b 0x3157ae7d 0x3157a699 0x314a0da3 0x31127c6b 0x3112347b 0x3112330d 0x31122d1f 0x31122b2f 0x3111c85d 0x2ecf91cd 0x2ecf6b71 0x2ecf6eb3 0x2ec61c27 0x2ec61a0b 0x33988283 0x31505049 0x6e2e1 0x6e268)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're accessing your `_tableData` with `indexPath.row` which starts at `NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS` after you created all static cells.

Let's assume you have 4 static cells and 6 dynamic cells. That's a total of 10 cells.
So after creating all static cells (`indexPath.row = 0 - 3`) it will create the dynamic cells with `indexPath.row = 4 - 9` even though your dataSource (`_tableData`) only has 6 elements. That's why you have to subtract the number of static cells when accessing `_tableData`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    CustomSideBarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

    //static cell
    if (indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS) { 
        cell.sidePic.image = _secondImage; 
        cell.sideOption.text = @"Everything"; 
        return cell; 
    }

    //dynamic cell
    cell.sidePic.image = _secondImage;
    //subtract the number of static rows to start at 0 for your dataSource
    _tempResults = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS]; 
    _optionCategory = [[_tempResults objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"category_name"]; 
    cell.sideOption.text = _optionCategory; 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: OMG! That did it! I knew it had to be something like that but could not articulate it into code! Thank you so much!!

Comment: oh wait i spoke too soon! There is something off. Visually, all the cells are showing...but when i tap for details (basically) the details are shifted up one.

Comment: can you paste your code for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Nevermind Hannes...i got it! I took family to get ice cream and realized it while i was driving. Thank you again so much!

Comment: that sounds perfect! have a nice day